# How to allow non-option arguments in any order to getopt?

Tags: c, getopt

I have a C program which expects to be called with several options and 1 non-option argument (i.e. with no associated option letter), and uses getopt to parse these options.  For example, it could be called with:

Example1:
    `myProgram -a "aParam" -b "bParam" "xParam"`

I have been using SLES10, and the options worked in any order.  For example, the non-option argument, "xParam" could come first:

Example2:
    `myProgram "xParam" -a "aParam" -b "bParam"`

However, when testing in SLES11, it seems that getopt stops processing as soon as it reaches a non-option parameter, so example 2 above does not work.

I've read the getopt man pages and seen that this may be relevant:

> If the first character of optstring is '+' or the environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, then option processing stops as soon as a nonoption argument is encountered.

I'm not sure if SLES11 sets POSIXLY_CORRECT by default.
What is the best way to get the old SLES10 getopt behaviour in SLES11?

Comment: type `set` on the terminal (unix etc) to see if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, perhaps?

Comment: `$ set | grep "POSIXLY_CORRECT"`
doesn't return anything, so maybe it is not set.

Comment: Perhaps still `POSIX_ME_HARDER` is in use?

Comment: Are you sure you have `getopt.h` included explicitly from your sources?

Comment: @WilliamMorris: `env` is a better way than `set` to inspect the environment.

Comment: @larsmans: system dependent perhaps? For me (MacOS) `env` gives a subset of `set` (28 against 58 variables).

Comment: @WilliamMorris: `set` prints the shell variables (and functions), which are indeed a superset of the environment variables. Only environment variables are passed to child processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that by default it was redirecting to _posix_getopt(), which was causing the behaviour I described above.

The possible solutions I found to this in the end:

1. Use getopt_long() instead.  This doesn't seem to have a posix equivalent.
2. Define _GNU_SOURCE, which stops the redirection.
3. Manually reorder the parameters, possibly using a wrapper shell script.

Comment: Apologies for the trivial edit - only way I could remove my accidental downvote (and turn it into an upvote).