# How to allow non-optional arguments to be in front of optional arguments using getopts in Bash?

Tags: bash, getopts

I know how to handle optional arguments using getopts in Bash

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:p:drh" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    a) echo $OPTARG;;
  esac
done
```

But if my script expects `./script.sh arg1 [options]`, how do I tell `getopts` to skip arg1?

```
$ ./script.sh -a 1234
1234
$ ./script.sh arg1 -a 1234
$ ./script.sh arg1
$ ./script.sh -a 1234 arg1
1234
```

As I see I can handle the argument if the argument is put in the last position. What "regex" do I need in the `getopts` to allow my positional argument to be in front of the optional argument?

The suggestions from [How to allow non-option arguments in any order to getopt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290788/how-to-allow-non-option-arguments-in-any-order-to-getopt) seems to be reordering the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of positional arguments then you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=$1
shift
echo $VAR

while getopts ":a:p:drh" opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    a) echo $OPTARG;;
  esac
done
```

Example:

```
> ./test.sh mist -a 2345 -p 45
mist
2345
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd do it. You can have many several non-optional arguments placed anywhere.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0]; do
  while getopts ":a:p:drh" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
      a) echo $OPTARG; shift;;
      p) echo $OPTARG; shift;;
      d) echo Option d;;
      r) echo Option r;;
      h) echo Option h;;
      \?) echo unknown Option;;
      :) echo missing required parameter for Option $OPT;;
    esac
    shift
    OPTIND=1
  done
  if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    POSITIONALPARAM=(${POSITIONALPARAM[@]} $1)
    shift
    OPTIND=1
  fi
done

echo ${POSITIONALPARAM[@]}
```

The inner loop parses the parameters. Whenever a non-option parameter is encountered, it will exit the inner loop. The external loop will grab the next non-option parameter. The inner loop will then pickup after the non-option parameter is removed then resumes reading the next optional parameters and so on.

As [Chrono Kitsune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539810/chrono-kitsune) suggested that I explain, the shift removes the first argument (optional or not) and moves everything one position to the left. `$1` is removed, `$2` becomes `$1`, `$3` becomes `$2` so on and so forth. This gives the script the control to move the non-optional argument until it becomes `$1`.

Both `shift` and resetting `OPTIND` make this possible. Thanks to [Chrono Kitsune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/539810/chrono-kitsune) for the suggestion that OPTIND should be reset to 1 instead of 0.

`./sample.bash -a one -p two more -d sample`

Output:

```
one
two
Option d
more sample
```

Now let's call the script with arguments in different positions.

`./sample.bash more -a one -p two -d sample`

Output:

```
one
two
Option d
more sample
```

Comment: `OPTIND` should be 1, not 0. Probably also a good idea to note where the `shift`'s are since they are crucial to this method.

Comment: OPTIND can be 0 or 1 as long as it isn't greater than 1. The only requirement is to reset OPTIND. However, if you do know that there are implementation where setting OPTIND to 0 does not work, then I'd have to start resetting to 1 instead of 0 as I've been used to. And thank you for taking the time to let me know. Knowledge is power.

Comment: "If the application sets OPTIND to the value 1, a new set of parameters can be used... Any other attempt to invoke getopts ... with an OPTIND value modified to be a value other than 1, produces unspecified results." [(Source)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/utilities/getopts.html)

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune - I updated it to reset `OPTIND` to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Cool, @alvits. I gave him the credit since he answered first and it was actually simpler to understand, but I did learn from your answer. Thanks. Upvoted!